# Angularjs directive with function two way bound falling into infinite loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I'm trying to create a custom directive to use a `<select>` combo with data in it. This directive has a change function being passed through, and using `ng-change` in the template. The function it calls is in the parent's scope, not in the isolated directive scope. For instance:

```
app.directive('selectDirective', function() {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'templates/myTemplate.html',
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',

        scope: {
            change: '=',
        }
        ...
    }
```

This directive is called like this: `<selectDirective change="myFunction()">`

As you can see, I'm using two way binding (`=`) in order to define functions in the parent's scope. It has to be this way because I update other `<select>`s when this function gets called. Notice that, within the parent's function I use the directive model to retrieve its id.

My problem is that once the parent's function is called, it falls into an infinite loop and I can't figure a way out. Any ideas?

Comment: use `&` to evaluate expression

Comment: "=" is used to bind simple variables. use "&" to bind functions instead

Comment: Was using `&` but had a problem with model sync. The model was changing after the function gets called.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the problem by wrapping the function with `$timeout` service. It adds the function into a queue and executes once angular is ready so the model is also synchronized.